# Multilingual Android application: how to structurize strings.xml?

Tags: android, android-studio, multilingual

Android offers a convenient way to develop multilngual app: it is sufficient to write each language versions for each string into porper strings.xml. However, in my (I think, not only in my) case there are a lot of strings to translate, and I'd like to distribute them onto some structure like directory|subdirectory. For example, I need to translate (among others) 12 month names, so it would be a good idea to create something like subdirectory `months` for them. I tried to use 'string-array' and wrote

```
<string-array name="months">
    <item name="Jan">January</item>
    <item name="Feb">February</item>
</string-array>
```

But translation editor doesn't recognise it; I think that the application will not recognize it as well.

Thanks in advance for any idea.

Comment: Have you reviewed the many hits on "android localization" search from within SO? If you take those search outside to duckduckgo.com or google you will get many hits such as this one https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization

Comment: Tommie C., thanks for reply and useful reference. I red that article previously, however now (while rereading) I noticed some useful tips delaing with several directories having different qualifiers.

Comment: You can just create several modules divided by your logic features and each of them can contain localization strings for each individual feature.

Comment: art, thanks for reply. I saw somewhat like your suggestion. However, it is well-known that each string (not marked as non-translated) must be included into each `strings.xml` for each value-?? directory. However, `string-array` can be included into some`strings.xml`, and not included into others. Is there some rule about that?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it is possible to insert `string-array` into different`strings.xml` for differents locales. It is impossible to use Translation Editor for such purpose, need this work manually for each `strings.xml`. Application recognizes such localization and use proper `strings.xml` for each locale.